# Error with setwd() when compile Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am doing an R markdown file, I have the last versión of R and RStudio, but I get an error when I trie to compile. My file is pretty simple, that's the reason why I don't know what it is happening.

I have already consulted this pages:

- [Shiny demo doesnt work: Error in setwd(old) : character argument expected #844](https://github.com/microsoft/RTVS/issues/844)
- [character argument expected #14](https://github.com/r-lib/rcmdcheck/issues/14)
- [Error for Knit to HTML](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-for-knit-to-html/42023)

But I can't found the problem.

This is the error:

```
setwd(wd): character argument expected

Error in setwd(wd) : character argument expected
Calls: <Anonymous> ... call_inline -> in_dir -> .handleSimpleError -> h -> setwd
Error in setwd(wd) : character argument expected
Calls: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> setwd -> .handleSimpleError -> h -> setwd
Error in setwd(oldwd) : character argument expected
Calls: <Anonymous> -> setwd
Execution halted
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you include the code chunk from the rmarkdown file which results in this error? It looks as if you may have an empty or erroneous call to `setwd(...)` somewhere.

Comment: I don't have it, because I just opened the default template of R Markdown (I mean: File >> New File >> R Markdown) and I have tried to compile that template :(

Comment: knitr will also run your .rprofile, what do you have in there

Comment: The base template for a .rmd does not include a call to `setwd()`. Perhaps you've chosen a template from the "Templates" tab? Regardless, if you post the .rmd we can help.